# How to check is a user is in a Domain group?

Tags: .net, windows, security, powershell

I want to check group membership of a user.  Group are taken from an ldap and inserted into a domain.  For the moment I tried something like this...

```
#Powershell.ps1
$CurrentUser = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$wp = New-Object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal($CurrentUser)
# I have in my domain a group called 'dom_group'
if ( $wp.IsInRole('dom_group') ) {
     "Expected to be true"
} else {
     "Unexpected False"
}
#Unexpected False
```

Unfortunately, this works only for local groups.

How can I check the group membership of the current use against the domain group 'dom_group'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work, but you must qualify the group name with the name of your domain: `$wp.IsInRole('mydomain\dom_group')` or `$wp.IsInRole('dom_group@mydomain')`.